# Procedure to edit PDF file in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, pdf, npm, edit

Need to include copyright content in footer of PDF document while initiating upload from the client side in ReactJS. Please suggest me if there any component/library that could be used in ReactJS

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow